# Autocomplete with Ajax and WordPress

Tags: autocomplete

based on [this this tutorial](http://markonphp.com/autocomplete-php-jquery-mysql-part2/) (I have to say that I'm a beginner) I've tried to realize a autocomplete function.

So for WP I've changed this Code

```
function searchForKeyword($keyword) {
$db = getDbConnection();
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name_en as country FROM `countries` WHERE name_en LIKE ? ORDER BY country");

$keyword = $keyword . '%';
$stmt->bindParam(1, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);

$isQueryOk = $stmt->execute();

$results = array();

if ($isQueryOk) {
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
} else {
  trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
}

$db = null; 

return $results;
```

to this

```
function searchForKeyword($keyword){
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'mytablename';

$keyword = $keyword . '%';
$stmt = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT name_en as country FROM $table_name WHERE name_en LIKE ? ORDER BY country", $keyword);

$isQueryOk = mysql_query($stmt);

$results = array();

if ($isQueryOk) {
    $results = mysql_fetch_column($stmt);
} else {
    trigger_error('Error executing statement.', E_USER_ERROR);
}

$db = null;

return $results;
```

But it always says

```
Call to a member function prepare() on null
```

I've spent hours on that and I'm not getting it to run. Can anyone help? Thanks...

Comment: have you read [how to use wpdb's prepare](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)? It doesn't work the same as PDO's prepare.

Comment: yes, I have read this. 
After that I've changed

`$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name_en as country FROM 'countries' WHERE name_en LIKE ? ORDER BY country");

$keyword = $keyword . '%';
$stmt->bindParam(1, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR, 100);`

To
`$stmt = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT name_en as country FROM $table_name WHERE name_en LIKE ? ORDER BY country", $keyword);`

But I guess it wasn't correct?